# #FRAME animation in mesh with armature and animation

Tags: animation, armature, drivers, unity

## Context

I have a main body mesh for which I have multiple accessories (hats, shirts etc). Each accessory is in a separate collection, all accessories are rigged and I have the model in Unity.

The main body has an animation and the accessories move/deform along with it. All good here.

## Problem

Some accessories are supposed to be animated. For instance, I have a propeller cap accessory like the one below (ignore the missing texture)

[image: Propeller cap]

I want to spin the propeller on top, independent from the rigged animation. For this, I animated the Z rotation property by adding `#FRAME/10`
However, this animation does not export to Unity.

What should I do? Any help is greatly appreciated! :)